# Stored procedure to compare two columns from different tables and make the insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two tables:

1. `Project` with fields `fld_id` (integer), `fld_allocated_hours` (integer), `fld_project_id` (integer)
2. `Timesheet` with columns `fld_id` (integer), `fld_allocated_time` (integer), `fld_project_id` (integer).

And I have this procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insert_allocated_time(p_project_id integer, p_allocated_time integer)
  RETURNS void 
  AS
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO dbo.Timesheet(fld_id, fld_project_id,fld_allocated_time)
from
(
  SELECT p.fld_id, p.fld_allocated_hours t.fld_allocated_time
  FROM dbo.Project p
  INNER JOIN dbo.Timesheet t
  ON p.fld_id=t.fld_id
  where t.fld_project_id = p_project_id
)AS Alias
GROUP BY fld_id, fld_allocated_days, fld_allocated_time
having SUM(fld_allocated_time) < fld_allocated_hours;
END;
```

All I want to make this procedure to insert the `allocated_time` value into the table `Timesheet` using the parameter `fld_project_id`  if  `SUM(fld_allocated_time)` from the table `Timesheet` is smaller or equal to `fld_allocated_hours` from the table `Project`, otherwise show an error message and exit.

How can I do this? I think my procedure code is not even close to what I want to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insert_allocated_time @p_project_id INT, @p_allocated_time INT
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @sum_alloc_time int, @alloc_hours int, @fld_id int

select @sum_alloc_time = SUM(fld_allocated_time)
from dbo.Timesheet
where fld_project_id = @p_project_id;

select @alloc_hours = p.fld_allocated_hours, @fld_id = p.fld_id
FROM dbo.Project p
INNER JOIN dbo.Timesheet t
ON p.fld_id=t.fld_id
where t.fld_project_id = @p_project_id;

IF @sum_alloc_time <= @alloc_hours
BEGIN
BEGIN TRAN;
INSERT INTO dbo.Timesheet(fld_id, fld_project_id,fld_allocated_time)
VALUES (@fld_id, @p_project_id, @p_allocated_time);
COMMIT TRAN;
END;

END;
```